# executar 2 métodos que exijam de recepção de áudio

Tags: java, android, mobile

estou com um problema aqui. Possuo 2 métodos, um deles mostra as ondas sonoras ou seja (você ativa ele e o que você falar ele interpreta em linhas), o outro quando é ativado ele grava o que a pessoa fala por exemplo.

Estou tentando executar os dois ao mesmo tempo, pois separados já funcionam. Caso alguém tenha uma ideia de como eu possa fazer isso, agradeço muito

Aqui esta o projeto em rar para download 
https://mega.nz/#!Q58R2RLL!8dvXYbJ_cQujyO8pv4bm73fZgkKsKDhZpteJc66Asf4

E aqui está a classe com os métodos separados

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
//REFERENTE AS ONDAS SONORAS. . .
int frequency = 8000;
int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT;
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private RealDoubleFFT transformer;
int blockSize = 256;

Button startStopButton;
boolean started = false;

RecordAudio recordTask;

ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
//REFERENTE A GRAVAÇÃO DE AUDIO. . .
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private String OUTPUT_FILE;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startStopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StartStopButton);
    startStopButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    transformer = new RealDoubleFFT(blockSize);

    imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) 256, (int) 100,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    OUTPUT_FILE= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/audioRecorder.3gpp";

}


//REFERENTE AS ONDAS. . .
public class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {
            // int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
            // AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);

            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);

            short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
            double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            // started = true; hopes this should true before calling
            // following while loop

            while (started) {
                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,
                        blockSize);

                for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                    toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed
                    // 16
                }                                       // bit
                transformer.ft(toTransform);
                publishProgress(toTransform);



            }

            audioRecord.stop();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(double[]... toTransform) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int i = 0; i < toTransform[0].length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            int downy = (int) (100 - (toTransform[0][i] * 10));
            int upy = 100;

            canvas.drawLine(x, downy, x, upy, paint);
        }

        imageView.invalidate();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (started) {
        started = false;
        startStopButton.setText("Start");
        recordTask.cancel(true);
    } else {
        started = true;
        startStopButton.setText("Stop");
        recordTask = new RecordAudio();
        recordTask.execute();
    }
}

//REFERENTE A GRAVAÇÃO. . .

public void buttonTaped(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.startBtn:
            try{
                beginRecording();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.finishBtn:
            try{
                stopRecording();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.playBtn:
            try{
                playRecording();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.stopBtn:
            try{
                stopPlayback();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void stopPlayback(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.stop();
}
private void playRecording() throws IOException {
    ditchMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

private void ditchMediaPlayer(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        try{
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void stopRecording(){
    if(recorder != null) recorder.stop();
}
private void beginRecording() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ditchMediaRecorder();
    File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

    if(outFile.exists()) outFile.delete();

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}

private void ditchMediaRecorder(){
    if(recorder != null) recorder.release();
}

}
```

E aqui está o xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>

<Button android:text="ondas"
android:id="@+id/StartStopButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="gravar"
    android:id="@+id/startBtn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="buttonTaped" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="finaliza a Gravação"
    android:id="@+id/finishBtn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="buttonTaped" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="escuta"
    android:id="@+id/playBtn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="buttonTaped" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="para de escutar"
    android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="buttonTaped" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Usei também as classes Complex1D, RealDoubleFFT e Real DoubleFFT_Mixed. Elas se encontrar no arquio rar que está para download

Existem botões também para parar gravação, reproduzi-la e parar reprodução que estava utilizando para testes.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, agradeço desde já pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa rodar esses dois métodos em threads separadas, da uma olhada na internet sobre run/start threads para a linguagem que está usando.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Leandro, ainda não tentei desta forma
vou tentar hoje mesmo e informo aqui caso tenha conseguido ou não
grande abraço!

Comment: Tentei qui, mas ocorreu os mesmos erros que estavam ocorrendo antes, quando rodo eles sozinhos dentro das threads funciona, mas quando rodo as duas juntos da problema.

Mas assim mesmo obrigado pela atenção, caso saiba de alguma outra possível alternativa, por favor comente  :)